# How do I handle interrupts (i.e. SIGTERM or SIGINT)

Tags: postgresql, plperl

I have a function that does quite a bit of intensive processing.  Once in awhile I need to be able to stop it (i.e. for DB maintenance) even if it's mid-run.  I'd like to send it a SIGINT so it can wind up what it's doing gracefully.  What I found was as soon as I introduce a normal perl interrupt handler, the function stops responding to interrupts properly.

Working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION run_for_awhile() RETURNS void
    AS $_X$
        spi_exec_query('select pg_sleep(30)');
$_X$
LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

If I do `select run_for_awhile()` in psql, I can type `Ctrl+C` and it cancels.  In the actual app I'd be doing `select pg_cancel_backend(PID)` but my tests have the same outcome via that method.

If I modify the function to capture SIGINT and/or SIGTERM, the signal gets sent, but the function doesn't notice it until after 30 seconds (when pg_sleep finishes).  So the handler does run eventually but not "immediately".

i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION run_for_awhile() RETURNS void
    AS $_X$
        $SIG{INT} = sub { die "Caught a sigint $!" };

        spi_exec_query('select pg_sleep(30)');
$_X$
LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

Comment: Hello there, perhaps the guys on http://dba.stackexchange.com can help you faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll need to do here is have your Perl interrupt handler invoke the same C code as the `CHECK_FOR_INTERRUPTS()` macro does, that is:

```
    if (InterruptPending)
        ProcessInterrupts();
```

(If you're on windows you need a bit more, see `src/include/miscadmin.h`).

Unfortunately there's no wrapper function you can call trivially, and plperl only seems to invoke `CHECK_FOR_INTERRUPTS` in `plperl_spi_prepare`.

So one option you have seems to be to set a global in your Perl interrupt handler that makes your app's main loop do a SELECT 1 when it sees the variable is set. Bit ugly, but it should work.

Otherwise you can possibly use Perl's `Inline::C` or similar to invoke `ProcessInterrupts`.

It'd be nice if plperl exposed a Perl wrapper for `CHECK_FOR_INTERRUPTS()`. Consider submitting a patch.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I'm not going to go that deep because I found a reasonable alternative... But this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to get completely to the bottom of this, but I found a way around it.  SIGINT and SIGTERM are not available, so don't use them.  But I can send another interrupt successfully, like SIGPROF.  Once that's sent, follow up with SIGINT and everything goes as expected.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION run_for_awhile() RETURNS void
    AS $_X$
        $SIG{PROF} = sub { die "Caught a sigprof $!" };

        spi_exec_query('select pg_sleep(30)');
$_X$
LANGUAGE plperlu;
```